# How to get the elastic search page increment elements

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have query to fetch the data from the elastic search

```
result = es.search(index="my_index", body={"size": 1000, "query": {"match_all": {}}})
print (result)
```

At one shot only i am bringing all elements

But  i need to keep incrementing lets say size 10 to 20, 20 to 30 like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `from` parameter:

```
result = es.search(index="my_index",
                   body={
                       "from": 10,     # <---------
                       "size": 10,
                       "query": {"match_all": {}}
                   })
```

Comment: if i have 3 pages and 25 elements does it increment by first page 10 data, second page next  10 elements and next page 5 elements

Comment: Yes. If you set it to 10 and it can only return 5, that's what it's gonna do.

Comment: THanks joe if i want result between 15 and 25 `result = es.search(index="my_index",   body={ "from": 15, "size": 10, "query": {"match_all": {}} })` does above query work

Comment: is from start from the index `0` or 1

Comment: can you check the below question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675696/how-to-get-the-individual-count-of-field-from-elasticsearch?noredirect=1#64675762