# How to get the individual count of field from Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, dsl

My content inside a dictionary is below

```
test=
[ { 'masterid': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Accounting', 'parentname': 'Finance'}, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Research', 'parentname': 'R & D' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }] }, 

{ 'masterid': '2', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Research', 'parentname': '' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Accounting', 'parentname': '' } ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Tester' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }]},

 { 'masterid': '3', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Engineering' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Engineering', 'parentname': '' } ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Developer' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer', 'parentname': '' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }]}]
```

Code is below to put into elastic search index

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.indices.create(index='new')
for e in test:
        es.index(index="new", body=e, id=e['id'])
```

I want to get the count of masterid of `BusinessArea` which is all the names

Here it is `Accounting`, `Research` `Engineering`

```
 [ {
      "name": "BusinessArea",
      "values": [
        {
          "name": "Accounting",
          "count": "2"
        },
        {
          "name": "Research",
          "count": "2"
        },
    {
          "name": "Engineering",
          "count": "1"
        }]
}]
```

or can i have answer like below

```
{
    "A": {
        "Designation": [{
                "key": "L1",
                "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
                "key": "L2",
                "doc_count": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "B": {
            "BusinessArea": [{
                    "key": "Accounting",
                    "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                    "key": "Research",
                    "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                    "key": "Engineering",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by *count of masterid of BusinessArea*

Comment: @Bhavya example Accounting appears two times in the `masterid` in test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the individual count of the field you can use the [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) that is a multi-bucket value source-based aggregation where buckets are dynamically built - one per unique value.

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "countNames": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "BusinessArea.name.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "countNames": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Accounting",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Research",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Engineering",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
```

**Update 1:**

If you want to have an individual count of the field for `Designation` as well as `BusinessArea`

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "countNames": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "BusinessArea.name.keyword"
      }
    },
    "designationNames": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Designation.name.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "designationNames": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "L1",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "L2",
          "doc_count": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    "countNames": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Accounting",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Research",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Engineering",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: @Nons do you want the count of individual fields OR count of all the documents?

Comment: I want individual counts only, if i want to get `Desgination` along with `BusinessArea` can i do  `{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "countNames": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "BusinessArea.name.keyword",
         "field": "Designation.name.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @Nons please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: designationNames which you give is not mandatory right?

Comment: Yes it is not mandatory, @Nons this is just the name of the bucket, you can replace (the name of bucket) `countNames` as well as `designationNames` according to your requirement :)

Comment: gotcha, Thanks for the answer, upvoting it

Comment: one last thing / I have update question, can i have `Designation` as key inside all information about `Designation`, `BusinessArea` as key and all information about `BusinessArea`

Comment: @Nons if you just want to change the name of the bucket, you can change them to `Designation` and `BusinessArea` also.

Comment: one question why you have given "size": 0 here

Comment: @Nons By default, searches containing an aggregation return both search hits and aggregation results. To return only aggregation results, I have set `size` to 0

Comment: can you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64694036/how-to-merge-two-dsl-query-for-aggregation-and-filter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224142/discussion-between-bhavya-and-nons).

Comment: joined the chat

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [count API of elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) to get the count of All the documents in the elasticsearch index or based on a condition as shown in the same doc.

For your case, it should be like

```
GET /<your-index-name>/_count?q=name:BusinessArea
```

Or, if `masterid` is the Unique-id in your document, you can simply use

```
 GET /<your-index-name>/_count
```

Comment: How to write in python?

Comment: @Nons, Sorry I am not familier with python syntax :(, but its very simple I believe, you just need to make a HTTP call with python :)