# How to merge two DSL query for aggregation and filter

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

- I need to search BusinessArea which is Research or Accounting this is array of fields(OR) statement
- I need to search Role is Developer or Tester condition this is array of fields(OR) statement
- I want to get the count of masterid of BusinessArea, designationNames, Role which is all the names
- Name filter is "Group1"

Below is the dictionary

```
test= [ { 'masterid': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ 'Accounting','Research'], 'Designation': [ 'L1' 'L2' ] }, { 'masterid': '2', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': ['Research','Accounting' ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Tester' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer' } ], 'Designation': [ 'L1' 'L2' ]}, { 'masterid': '3', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ 'Engineering' ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Developer' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer', 'parentname': '' } ], 'Designation': [ 'L1' 'L2' ]}]
```

Below is the aggregation function

```
    {
      "size": 0,
      "aggs": {
        "countNames": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "BusinessArea.keyword"
          }
        },
        "designationNames": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Designation.keyword"
          }
        },
        "Role": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Role.name.keyword"
          }
        }
    
      }
    }
```

Below is the filtering query

```
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "BusinessArea.keyword": [
                  "Research",
                  "Accounting"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "Role.name.keyword": [
                  "Developer",
                  "Tester"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

```
"filter": [
   "term": {
    "name.keyword": "Group1"}]
```

I need to merge both query and output will be having from the both

Comment: i tried merging RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Expected [START_OBJECT] but found [START_ARRAY]')

Comment: search= es.search(index="4", body=quer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice start !!! Now you can simply combine all those snippets like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name.keyword": "Group1"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "BusinessArea.keyword": [
              "Research",
              "Accounting"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "Role.name.keyword": [
              "Developer",
              "Tester"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "countNames": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "BusinessArea.keyword"
      }
    },
    "designationNames": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Designation.keyword"
      }
    },
    "Role": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Role.name.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when  i take this i got RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Expected [START_OBJECT] but found [START_ARRAY]')

Comment: Don't mind my asking, but are you sure you copy/pasted the query correctly? Can you share the full error? Can you show your python code assembling the query, it's probably where the culprit is?

Comment: My both query is working `quer = {'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'terms': {'BusinessArea.keyword': ['Silver', 'Gold']}}], 'filter': [{'term': {'name.keyword': 'Group1'}}]}}}
`


`q = { "size": 0, "aggs": { "BusinessArea": { "terms": { "field": "BusinessArea.keyword" } }, "Designation": { "terms": { "field": "Designation.keyword" } }, "Role": { "terms": { "field": "Role.name.keyword" } } } }`

Comment: Show your code (update your question), please, the error must be there somewhere

Comment: error is coming because this aggregation will come different output and match will give different output, how to solve this?

Comment: Without seeing the code that assembles this, it's hard to know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224143/discussion-between-nons-and-val).

Comment: first did aggregation and then did filtering, it worked

Comment: just asking, aggregation after filtering and filtering after aggregation is same right?

Comment: Yes, the order doesn't matter.